# Pandas не находит файл

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas не читает файлы, хотя я ставлю `\\` и поменял через `ch.dir()` каталог, указывал полный путь и все равно он отказывается его находить.
Сам код:

```py
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('C:\\code')
pd.read_csv('C:\\code\\1.csv')
```

Вот конец текста ошибки:

> File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:856, in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
> 851 elif isinstance(handle, str):
> 852     # Check whether the filename is to be opened in binary mode.
> 853     # Binary mode does not support 'encoding' and 'newline'.
> 854     if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
> 855         # Encoding
> --> 856         handle = open(
> 857             handle,
> 858             ioargs.mode,
> 859             encoding=ioargs.encoding,
> 860             errors=errors,
> 861             newline="",
> 862         )
> 863     else:
> 864         # Binary mode
> 865         handle = open(handle, ioargs.mode)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\code\1.csv'

Comment: Смотря на картинку, как я понял вы используете `Jupyter` я думаю проблема не в `python`, а именно в нем. [Вот](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory/13102) первый сайт по запросу вашей ошибки, возможно на нем есть решение вашей проблемы.

Comment: Перезапускал ядро, не помогает. В командной строке не импортирует модули, такое ощущение, что он вообще не хочет находить ничего в папках.
*Вру, в командной строке запускает модули при смене каталога на папку, где он находится, но все равно не находит в самом юпитере.

Comment: строчка ``os.chdir('C:\\code')`` вообще не нужна

Comment: а файл-то есть?

Comment: Да, лежит в папке

Comment: Объясните мне пожалуйста, что неправильно я делаю

Comment: Возможно такое, что это все из-за кириллицы на пути установки самой анаконды?

Comment: А если в юпитере набрать `!dir c:\\code` что напишет? Так файл видно, есть он в списке файлов?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо абсолютных путей всегда стараюсь использовать относительные пути. Создаем директорию с кодом C:\code, внутрь него пихаем скрипт. Создаем поддиректорию C:\code\dat и туда кладем 1.csv

В коде пишем `df1 = pd.read_csv('./dat/1.csv')` (в именах пути на питоне легче использовать такие наклонные палки).

PS. можно и через библиотеку pathlib, но как по мне это излишне.

Answer (score 0):

Нет другой возможности чем та, что в вашей папке

```
C:\code
```

на самом деле **не существует файл 1.csv.  Точка.**

---

Может быть, ваш файл называется **не** `1.csv`, **а** `l.csv`, т.е. **не цифра** `1`, а **буква** `L`.

---

*Примечания:*

1. Возможно использовать тоже обычные слеши (`/`):

   ```
   pd.read_csv('C:/code/1.csv')
   ```

   Да. И в Windows.
2. Лучше чем писать путь или имя файла *вручную*, является *копировать / вставить* их, чтобы избежать таких ошибок.